# SQLALCHEMY is not loading

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, ibm-cloud

Hello: I am trying to connect to a db2 database and use sqlalchemy but I get the following error:

```
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection: dict_keys([]) Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

The code I'm using to connect is below and it works fine in the same notebook when I run it on Cognitive Class. I just can't get it to work on kaggle:

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

`sqlalchemy`, `ibmdb`, `ibmdbsa`, `ibmdb_dbi` are all installed.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide more details, what is the full code? What plugin are you using?

Comment: Hello @data_henrik: Thanks for the reply. The error that I get is above verbatim. The code that I'm using to make the connection -- and that produces that error -- is above, except I've changed the user name and password. The following relevant modules installed are: ibm-db 3.0.1, ibm-db-sa 0.3.5, SQLAlchemy 1.3.16. Thanks for your help -- this has been frustrating!

Comment: I have used Db2 in notebooks in the past, see https://blog.4loeser.net/2016/11/sql-magic-in-notebooks-in-ibm-data.html Not sure which %sql command you are using, but I had to use `%sql db2+ibm_db://...` as URI

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. I am using `%sql ibm_db_sa://...` but I did try your method but it didn't work. I got the same message. I also liked your blog post and followed it, but got the same result. Thank you for your help! I'll keep searching.